# Hidden fonts Windows Server 2008

Tags: fonts, windows-server-2008

We have a Windows Server 2008 machine which we need to perform report template design work on (I realise this is not ideal - it's simply down to budget).  As many/most of the fonts on my Windows Server 2008 installation are hidden, this causes an issue as certain fonts assumed to be active are not.  Is there an problem if I Show (i.e. make available) all currently hidden fonts - eg. for reasons of memory, exposes vulnerabilities, etc
Many thanks
Travis

Answer (score 0):

Turns out [there's a Microsoft KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/967744) about disappearing fonts in Windows Server 2008 and Vista. It appears there is a hotfix, although I'm not sure which specific one, but it does suggest [updating to the latest Service Pack](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/935791) for Windows.

Comment: I can see *all* the fonts (the hidden ones are greyed out waiting to be shown if desired), however I wondered whether I should "Show" the ones that are hidden (note that there are more hidden fonts than those shown) - i.e. what are the ramifications - memory, vulnerability, etc